# from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher as pub ImportError: cannot import name Publisher

Tags: python

I am building the software dicompyler from its github source - https://github.com/bastula/dicompyler. when I compile the file named dicompyler_app.py, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dicompyler_app.py", line 10, in <module>
    import dicompyler.main
  File "F:\UIC masters\CS 522 - Human Computer Interaction\Liz Research\dicompyler-master\dicompyler\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from main import start, __version__
  File "F:\UIC masters\CS 522 - Human Computer Interaction\Liz Research\dicompyler-master\dicompyler\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher as pub
ImportError: cannot import name Publisher
```

I am executing this on Windows 10, with a Python compiler. I also downloaded and installed wxPyhton from this link http://www.wxpython.org/download.php

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely using a newer version of wxPython than dicompyler supports. Please install wxPython 2.8. The build requirements for dicompyler are listed [here](https://github.com/bastula/dicompyler/wiki/BuildRequirements).

There is a [branch](https://github.com/bastula/dicompyler/tree/dependencyupdate) that I am working on that will update the dependency requirements, but it is still a work in progress.

Please see or use the dicompyler discussion group, as this question has been asked there before: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dicompyler/spkWot4wEj0/2L2nwX5gowQJ